# Add a scrollbar to a Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if I can add a scrollbar to a `Label` or not?

I followed [this tutorial](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/) to create a simple terminal GUI with a `Button` and a `TextField`. The problem is that, unlike what's in the tutorial , I need my `Label` to contain more than just a single line

Any alternatives? I want something exactly like this tutorial, but with more lines and a scrollbar for the `Label` (I already limited its size, but no scrollbar).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a scrollbar to a `Label`.

If you want multiple lines of text that can be scrolled, use a `Text` widget.